# CSS de temas Magento

Tags: css, magento

Adicionei um tema no Magento e gostaria de mudar o background e algumas outras coisas através do style.css. Eu faço as modificações, só que não dá certo. Alguém sabe por quê?

O CSS que estou abrindo se encontra em "skin/frontend/default/theme-001/css".

Comment: Marchioro, dá para descrever mais o que tentou? que propriedade/atributo do CSS tentou mudar?, fez refresh do browser?, quando vai ver o código da página as suas mudanças estão no CSS?

Comment: Sergio, eu tentei mudar varios atributos, como background, margin, border, mais nada deu certo, fiz o refresh do browser mais msm assim não dá, eu não intendi essa sua ultima pergunta, :/

Comment: Se fôr ver o código da página carregada (source code) pode encontrar o ficheiro CSS. Dê uma olhada se as alterações estão lá.

Comment: Desculpa mais ainda não intendi, é que so novo no magento, rsr

Comment: No browser, com a página aberta, fazendo clic com botão direito ou no menu (depende do browser) dá para escolher "view source code", ou abrindo a consola com F12 dá para ver os estilos e mesmo ficheiros carregados. Seria interessante saber se as alterações que fêz lá estão. Se tiver um link pode postar aqui.

Answer (score 3):

## Magento e suas configurações

É preciso garantir que o Magento está a enviar o ficheiro de CSS do tema correcto. Pode parecer básico, mas acontece com alguma frequência, em especial nos casos onde usamos vários temas.

Confirma nas configurações que está escolhido o tema pretendido:

```
admin → System → Design → Themes → Skin
```

ou verifica o código no teu `.phtml`.

Se estiveres a incluir o teu ficheiro a partir de um *template*, verifica se o URL está construído da seguinte forma:

```php
href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/nome-do-ficheiro.css')?>"
```

<sup>Créditos para a secção "Magento e suas configurações" para o utilizador @DavidL [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7573997/352449) no SOEN.</sup>

---

## Cache no navegador

Quando realizas uma alteração numa folha de estilos e após actualizares a página a alteração em questão não se encontra evidenciada, geralmente está relacionado com cache e é preciso dizer ao navegador que deve recolher o ficheiro novamente.

Assim sendo, assumindo que:

- Se aplicável, o ficheiro alterado foi enviado para o servidor com sucesso;
- O ficheiro efectivamente existe e está a ser carregado:

  Se o ficheiro existe em `skin/frontend/default/theme-001/css` como indicas na pergunta, o mesmo pode ser aberto no navegador se aplicares o resto do caminho para o mesmo:

  ```
  http://www.meu-site.com/skin/frontend/default/theme-001/css/style.css
  └──────────┬───────────┘└─────────────────┬────────────────┘└───┬───┘
             ↓                              ↓                     ↓
    domínio ou localhost          caminho para o ficheiro       nome
      consoante o caso              a começar onde está          do
                                 o index.php ou index.html    ficheiro
                                                              alterado
  ```

  <sup>o caminho completo para o ficheiro de css que estás a alterar a começar na raiz do projecto, normalmente onde está o `index.php` ou `index.html` precedido do domínio.</sup>

Podes dizer ao navegador que puxe de novo todos os ficheiros de uma página através do usos das teclas <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> que ao invés da regular actualização da página vai efectivamente forçar a recolha de todos os anexos do documento (css, scripts, images, etc.).

---

#### Considerações a ter em conta

Ao alterarmos estilos, por vezes os mesmos não tem efeito porque estão a ser declarados com maior prioridade numa outra folha de estilos ou na mesma mas num outro lugar.

Tudo depende da forma como estão declarados na folha de estilos e da posição dessa folha de estilos na *markup*.

---

#### Ver código fonte da página

Outra forma de avaliar se as alterações estão no ficheiro que está a ser utilizado na página que estás a visualizar, ou se o mesmo está a ser utilizado de todo já foi referida pelo @Sergio nos comentários:

Podes usar as teclas de atalho para abrir o código fonte da página actual:

- Firefox: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>
- Chrome: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>
- Safari: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>

  De notar que no caso do Safari é preciso estar activo o menu do programador:

  - Safari menu → Preferências → Avançadas;
  - Marcar "Apresentar o menu do programador na barra de menu".
- Internet Explorer: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> ou nas novas versões <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>

Comment: Queria poder votar duas vezes, só porque a formatação ficou muito bem feita.

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues Demorei 1 hora a fazer esta resposta, pelo menos que esteja bem formatada :) (ps: Tks!)